# PHP Remove/Replace string from a text file

Tags: php, preg-replace

If i have a text file that contain data of names:

```
John
Ham
Joe
Tope
Nalawas
```

i want php to look for Joe and remove it from the list. Any idea?

my idea:

```
<?php
$lines = file('user.txt');
$word = '';
$result = '';

foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(substr($line) == 'joe') {
        $result .= $word."\n";
    } else {
        $result .= $line;
    }
}

file_put_contents('user.txt', $result);

?>
```

this code is not working i want to use preg-replace

Comment: Open the file, read each line and check for the value wanted.

Comment: `substr()` expects two parameters, don't you get error/warning messages?

Comment: i dont get any error message

Comment: IF you want to replace `Joe`, don't look for `joe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works well.
But as mentioned will remove Joesephine, too

```
$lines  = file('names.txt');
$search = 'joe';

$result = '';
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(stripos($line, $search) === false) {
        $result .= $line;
    }
}
file_put_contents('names2.txt', $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$result = str_replace('Joe','',$line);`

As a reminder this approach will work in the case you mentioned, but if there were names like "Joesephine" it would produce line: sephine

Also might want to check out: `strtolower()` when comparing strings like this to account for case-insensitivity http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Comment: where exactly to use that?

Comment: do you want to replace with my foreach loop?

Comment: Yes that should be the entire foreach loop. 1 line so just replace that

Comment: foreach($lines as $line){$result = str_replace('joe','',$line);} like this

Comment: Wouldn't do anything for OP because there's no "joe" anywhere in OP's text